# SplitView: UIToolbar Layout Issues When Navigating into Detail

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have encountered a layout issue when using a UIToolbar at the bottom of my detail view. The setup is pretty much the default Master-Detail sample provided by Xcode.

When you choose to add a toolbar to the detail navigation controller, this bar jumps on appearance.

Here's what I've done in IB:

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix?

Comment: It depends how you want to fix it. You can make transition smooth, or you can drop safe area constraint and make adjustment manually. First you need to describe what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: I want to prevent the bar from jumping when it appears. So, the best solution would be that the red area already has its final height when it appears. Any idea how to achieve this?